# What is the name of this homotopy?

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition

Here is my definition for homotopy:

> Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces.
>
> Let $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ be continuous functions.
>
> If there is a function $F:X\times[0,1]\rightarrow Y$ such that $F(x,0)=f(x)$ and $F(x,1)=g(x)$, then $F$ is called a homopoty between $f,g$ and $f,g$ are said to be homotopic.

However my professor defined homotopy in the following way:

> Let $X,Y$ be topolgicial spaces and $A\subset X$.
>
> Let $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ be continuous functions such that $f=g$ on $A$.
>
> If there is a function $F:X\times[0,1]\rightarrow Y$ such that $F(x,0)=f(x)$ and $F(x,1)=g(x)$ and $F(a,t)=f(a) (a\in A, t\in [0,1])$ then $F$ is called a homopoty between $f,g$ on $A$ and $f,g$ are said to be homotopic on $A$.
>
> If $A=\emptyset$, we call $f,g$ are homotopic.

I think my professors definition is extremely weird. I have looked up a page at wikipedia about homotopy, but I couldn't see any category about this.

What is this homotopy called generally? (i.e. In my language, homotopy such that $F(a,t)=f(a) (a\in A, t\in [0,1]$))

Comment: That's pretty standard. It's usually called a homotopy relative to $A$ or rel $A$. Why do you think it's weird?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey so I was just on Wikipedia and able to find a section that has what you are asking about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Relative_homotopy